# Regular expression to modify upper and lower case in units

Tags: python, regexp-replace

I'm having a problem creating a regular expression (or is there a better way?).
I have products like '2L cans', '500mL cans', '1.5Kg box', etc. (my products are in French in this form 'bidon de 2L'). My aim is to clean up these units. For example, all 'L' and 'K' must be capitalized and all other letters lower case. However, I can't get good results. I still have a problem with 'ml' not becoming 'mL'.
Similarly, the units have to be stuck to the number in front.
Is anyone good at regex and know what the problem is? Here's my current code with an example of my data:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {
    'product': [
        'le paquet de 3,315 Kg',
        'les 4 bidons de 3,01L',
        'la recharge de 999 ml',
        'le paquet de 4,87kg',
        'les 2 bidons de 2,63l',
        'la recharge de 1,8 l',
        'les 3 bidons de 1,75 L'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


pattern = r"(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)$"

def correct_unit(match):
    number = match.group(1)
    unit = match.group(2)
    unit = re.sub(r'\b([kl])([g])?\b', lambda m: m.group(1).upper() + (m.group(2).lower() if m.group(2) else ''), unit, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    #unit = re.sub(r'ml', 'mL', unit, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    #unit = re.sub(r'cl', 'cL', unit, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return number + unit

df['product'] = df['product'].str.replace(pattern, correct_unit, regex=True)

print(df['product'])
```

Here's the results :

0     le paquet de 3,315Kg
1    les 4 bidons de 3,01L
2     la recharge de 999ml
3      le paquet de 4,87kg
4    les 2 bidons de 2,63l
5      la recharge de 1,8L
6    les 3 bidons de 1,75L

But I would like to have :

0     le paquet de 3,315Kg
1    les 4 bidons de 3,01L
2     la recharge de 999mL
3      le paquet de 4,87Kg
4    les 2 bidons de 2,63L
5      la recharge de 1,8L
6    les 3 bidons de 1,75L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a case insensitive match, make all chars lowercase, set the first char to uppercase and flip the cases when the string ends with `l`

For the pattern you can make use of character classes with an alternation:

```
(?i)\b(\d+)\s*([kl]g|[mc]?l)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for a case insensitive match
- `\b(\d+)` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match, then capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `([kl]g|[mc]?l)` Capture **group 2**, match either `kg` `lg` OR `ml` `cl` or `l`
- `\b` A word boundary

**Note** that if the match must be at the end of the string, you can replace the ending `\b` with `$`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uVg6Ml/1).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'product': [
        'le paquet de 3,315 Kg',
        'les 4 bidons de 3,01L',
        'la recharge de 999 ml',
        'le paquet de 4,87kg',
        'les 2 bidons de 2,63l',
        'la recharge de 1,8 l',
        'les 3 bidons de 1,75 L',
        'le paquet de 4,87KG',
        'la recharge de 999 ML',
        'la recharge de 999 cl'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pattern = r"(?i)\b(\d+)\s*([kl]g|[mc]?l)\b"

def correct_unit(match):
    unit = match.group(2).lower().title()
    if unit.endswith('l'):
        unit = unit.swapcase()
    return match.group(1) + unit

df['product'] = df['product'].str.replace(pattern, correct_unit, regex=True)

print(df['product'])
```

Output

```
0     le paquet de 3,315Kg
1    les 4 bidons de 3,01L
2     la recharge de 999mL
3      le paquet de 4,87Kg
4    les 2 bidons de 2,63L
5      la recharge de 1,8L
6    les 3 bidons de 1,75L
7      le paquet de 4,87Kg
8     la recharge de 999mL
9     la recharge de 999cL
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's working very well and it's very clear :)

Answer (score 0):

You're always using first upper then lower - which doesn't make sense for mL.

But let's see what you said:

> For example, all 'L' and 'K' must be capitalized and all other letters lower case.

Just do that!

Grab the letters and just force it lowercase, then change k into K and l into L.

Now, let's see the pattern you have:

```py
pattern = r"(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)$"
```

The units are in second group, there's no need to have additional pattern, just operate on `m.group(2)` directly - using normal string operations, like `m.group(2).lower().replace("k", "K").replace("l", "L")` and add the number itself before that.

Now, I don't know pandas (and I don't have it installed to test it, oops), but I believe together should look like:

```
pattern = r"(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)$"
df['product'] = df['product'].str.replace(pattern, lambda m: m.group(1)+m.group(2).lower().replace("k", "K").replace("l", "L"), regex=True)
```